# Hypothesis testing and exponentially decreasing errors

Tags: statistics, information-theory

We observe independent drawings from an unknown distribution $Q$ on the finite set $A$. Let $\gamma$ be a positive
number and let $P_0$ and $P_1$ be strictly positive distributions on $A$ with $D(P_1||P_0) > \gamma$.

To test the null-hypothesis $Q = P_0$ against the simple alternative hypothesis $Q = P_1$, let the acceptance region $A_n \subset X^n$ be the union of all type classes $|T_P^n|$ with $D(P||P_0) \leq \gamma$.

How can I show that then the probability of type 1 error decreases with exponent $\gamma$, i.e.,

$$P_0^n(X^n-A_n) = 2^{-n\gamma+o(n)} (\mbox{or, i.e., } \mbox{lim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log P_0^n(X^n-A_n)=-\gamma,$$

where the type 2 error probability $(P_1^n(A_n))$ decreases with exponent $\delta = D(P^∗||P_1)$ where $P^∗$ is the I projection of P1 onto the "divergence ball",

$$B_(P_0, \gamma) = \{P \mid D(P||P_0) \leq \gamma \}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is one of those standard textbook results that are not too hard to show with enough background, but are lengthy. I'm not sure this forum is appropriate for these. You should find this result, (or something close) in most large deviations texts.

Comment: A high level proof strategy - using Sanov's theorem, the continuity of $D(P\|P_0), D(P\|P_1)$ in $P$, and compactness of the set of distributions on a finite alphabet, you should be able to show the result for type-based tests (i.e., tests whose acceptance regions are unions of type sets). To complete the argument, try to show the following: if there is a test which achieves missed detection and false alarm error rates of $(\alpha_n, \beta_n),$ then there exists a type-based test with corresponding error rates bounded by $2\alpha_n$ and $2\beta_n$ respectively.